# How to add an Xively HTTP trigger to send data to thingspeak

Tags: triggers, cosm, xively

I want to add an Xively HTTP trigger, but I don't know how to insert the current value into the URL.  For example, I have the URL
http://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=jkldfskladfsfdfs&field8=

I want the Xively trigger to insert the current value of my stream after the = sign.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers from Xively make a POST request containing information on the triggering datastream and its conditions to the server you specified when setting up the trigger.

You can't specify the current value as a GET parameter unless you write your own simple service to accept the trigger and then forward the data on to Thingspeak.